# javamail api gmail authentication occure error

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

```
E/MailApp(16209): Could not send email
E/MailApp(16209): javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
E/MailApp(16209):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
E/MailApp(16209):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
E/MailApp(16209):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
E/MailApp(16209):   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
E/MailApp(16209):   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
E/MailApp(16209):   at AlarmSpy.Email.GMailSender.send(GMailSender.java:104)
E/MailApp(16209):   at AlarmSpy.MotionDetectionActivity.Email(MotionDetectionActivity.java:1267)
E/MailApp(16209):   at AlarmSpy.MotionDetectionActivity.access$9(MotionDetectionActivity.java:1247)
E/MailApp(16209):   at AlarmSpy.MotionDetectionActivity$SavePhotoTask.onPostExecute(MotionDetectionActivity.java:1134)
E/MailApp(16209):   at AlarmSpy.MotionDetectionActivity$SavePhotoTask.onPostExecute(MotionDetectionActivity.java:1)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/MailApp(16209):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
E/MailApp(16209):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/MailApp(16209):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/MailApp(16209):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
E/MailApp(16209):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
E/MailApp(16209):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note : when I am using different Country then its through error.(In browser Account verification page shown when login)

Comment: can you post code? Logcat is not enough here.

Comment: you can download the source code here.
    http://www.ziddu.com/download/14286605/SendMMS3.zip.html

Gmail account create in UK and access in India Country so,its through error.

Comment: The protocol trace might provide more clues.  See the JavaMail FAQ.

Comment: solved this issue. Thanks duds.

Comment: Hello, can u pls lemme know how did u solve this.. am getiing the same err.